# @RequiredStringValidator using an expression

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, annotations

I'm using struts 2 & validation annotations. I need to validate a field which is required if another is true or false. I was using @RequiredStringValidator but I realized this annotation doesn't have the expression property.

```
    @Validations(requiredStrings =
{@RequiredStringValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "username", message = "El Usuario es requerido",key="security.admin.user.username.required"),
 @RequiredStringValidator( type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "password", message = "El Password es requerido",key="security.admin.user.password.required")}...
```

The field to validate is "password" but it's only required if "autoGeneratePassword" field is false.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validations requiring expression evaluation don't use Simple `RequiredStringValidation` instead you can use [`FieldExpressionValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/FieldExpressionValidator.html) or [`ExpressionValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/ExpressionValidator.html)

One way of using it:

```
@FieldExpressionValidator(fieldName="password",key="security.admin.user.password.required",message="El Password es requerido",expression="checkAutoPassword()")

private boolean checkAutoPassword(){
  return false;
}
```

You can use OGNL expression to do the same.